# AttributeError: 'PathCollection' object has no property 'markeredgecolor'

Tags: python, matplotlib, marker

I'm trying to add markeredgecolor on my plot (marker='.' and I want markers to be surrounded by different colors depending on their characteristics).

I tried to do like this with geographic data : https://python-graph-gallery.com/131-custom-a-matplotlib-scatterplot/

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (8,6)) 
df.plot(ax=ax,color='green', marker=".", markersize=250)
df2.plot(ax=ax,color='green', marker=".", markerfacecolor="orange", markersize=250)
```

However I get this error :

```
AttributeError: 'PathCollection' object has no property 'markeredgecolor'
```

Do you know what's the problem and what to do ?

Edit - with a reproducible example :

```
#Packages needed
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas as gpd
import shapely.wkt

#Creating GeoDataFrame df2
df2 = pd.DataFrame([shapely.wkt.loads('POINT (7.23173 43.68249)'),shapely.wkt.loads('POINT (7.23091 43.68147)')])
df2.columns=['geometry']
df2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df2)
df2.crs = {'init' :'epsg:4326'}

#Ploting df2
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df2.plot(ax=ax,color='green', marker=".", markerfacecolor="orange")
```

Comment: I think your code is the plotting function provided by pandas and it doesn't have the color of the marker edge. What you are referring to is maplotlib.

Comment: What versions of pandas and matplotlib are you using? This works for me

Comment: Thank you for these answers ! @r-beginners you mean that I'm not using matplotlib here, right ? (I didn't understand why there were 2 ways to do graphs on Python, it must be that !)

Comment: @DavidG I'm on pandas 1.1.3 and matplotlib 3.3.1. And you ?

Comment: That combination of versions also works for me. Can you create a [mcve]?

Comment: @DavidG, I've just done it. To precise : it works without "markerfacecolor="orange"", but not with this parameter

Answer (score 5):

Geopandas `plot` does not accept all arguments as matplotlib.plot (reference [here])(https://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.plot.html)

However, there is some `**style_kwds` that can do the work for you (not clearly explained in the docs though):

Taking back your code

```py
df2.plot(
    ax=ax,
    color='green',
    marker=".",
    markersize=1000,
    edgecolor='orange', # this modifies the color of the surrounding circle
    linewidth=5 # this modifies the width of the surrounding circle
)
```

Having this configuration in `requirements.txt`

```
geopandas~=0.9.0
matplotlib~=3.3.4
pandas~=1.2.3
shapely~=1.7.1
```

Comment: Hmm, I got this error :/ "AttributeError: 'PathCollection' object has no property 'kind'"

Comment: Just edited the answer with the corresponding versions of packages ;-)